# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing where attribute in the options parameter. sequelize findALl

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm using findAll in sequelize for a website's use register checking, but always get the error message:"AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing where attribute in the options parameter". My code is real easy as below:

```
var checkRegister = function (data, callback){
    userModel.findAll({
        'where': {
            '$and': [
             {'phoneNumber' : data.phoneNumber},
             {'password' : 
                 {$ne : null }
             }
            ]
        }
    }).then(callback).catch(function(e) {
    console.log('find user error,', e);
    throw e;
});
```

}

my sequelize version 4.37.10, could anyone give some suggestion? Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need quotes in `where` and you can also do without `and`. Something like this

```
var checkRegister = function (data, callback){
    userModel.findAll({
        where: {
          phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
          password: { [Op.ne]: null }
        }
    }).then(callback).catch(function(e) {
    console.log('find user error,', e);
    throw e;
});
```